# What is the meaning of "... ..." token? i.e. double ellipsis operator on parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

While browsing through gcc's current implementation of new C++11 headers, I stumbled upon "......" token. You can check, that the following code [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/4GfbYYb75) [via godbolt.org].

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{ /* ... */ };

template <typename T, typename ... U>
struct X<T(U......)> // this line is the important one
{ /* ... */ };
```

So, what is the meaning of this token?

edit: Looks like SO trimmed "......" in question title to "...", I did really mean "......" . :)

Comment: hint: it is `...` followed by `...` .

Comment: Is it not more like `U...` followed by `...` . Very odd nonetheless.

Comment: Note: This can be found in `<functional>` and `<type_traits>`, always in the context of a function argument list inside a template parameter.

Comment: only way I found to make it stuck in the title was to put a space inbetween... hope it makes it clearer for the readers.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Thanks, much better!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Every instance of that oddity is paired with a case of a regular single ellipsis.

```
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct _Weak_result_type_impl<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    { typedef _Res result_type; };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct _Weak_result_type_impl<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
    { typedef _Res result_type; };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct _Weak_result_type_impl<_Res(_ArgTypes...) const>
    { typedef _Res result_type; };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct _Weak_result_type_impl<_Res(_ArgTypes......) const>
    { typedef _Res result_type; };
```

My guess is that the double ellipsis is similar in meaning to `_ArgTypes..., ...`, i.e. a variadic template expansion followed by a C-style varargs list.

[Here's a test](http://ideone.com/8TQAa) supporting that theory… I think we have a new winner for worst pseudo-operator ever.

**Edit:** This does appear to be conformant. §8.3.5/3 describes one way to form the parameter list as

> parameter-declaration-list<sub>opt</sub> ...<sub>opt</sub>

So the double-ellipsis is formed by a parameter-declaration-list ending with a parameter pack, followed by another ellipsis.

The comma is purely optional; §8.3.5/4 does say

> Where syntactically correct and where “...” is not part of an abstract-declarator, “, ...” is synonymous with “...”.

This *is* within an abstract-declarator, **[edit]** but Johannes makes a good point that they are referring to an abstract-declarator within a parameter-declaration. I wonder why they didn't say "part of a parameter-declaration," and why that sentence isn't just an informative note…

Furthermore, `va_begin()` in `<cstdarg>` requires a parameter before the varargs list, so the prototype `f(...)` specifically allowed by C++ is useless. Cross-referencing with C99, it is illegal in plain C. So, this is most bizarre.

**Usage note**

By request, [here is a demonstration](http://ideone.com/SwySs) of the double ellipsis:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template< typename T >
T const &printf_helper( T const &x )
    { return x; }

char const *printf_helper( std::string const &x )
    { return x.c_str(); }

template< typename ... Req, typename ... Given >
int wrap_printf( int (*fn)( Req... ... ), Given ... args ) {
    return fn( printf_helper( args ) ... );
}

int main() {
    wrap_printf( &std::printf, "Hello %s\n", std::string( "world!" ) );
    wrap_printf( &std::fprintf, stderr, std::string( "Error %d" ), 5 );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. T(U..., ...) however compiles fine, too; perhaps they wanted to save some space. :)

Comment: But what would that mean? And how can the compiler tell where _ArgTypes end and some "extra" parameters start?

Comment: @Bo Persson: `std::is_function`'s `value` must be true even if the function is C varargs one and because T(U...) is **not** match for such function, you need this madness. E.g. int f(int, char, ...) matches T(U......) exactly with T = int, U = {int, char} and the "..." varargs token.

Comment: @Vitus - Ok, thanks I guess. I was just considering a new question "When is this useful?" to earn my first Tubleweed badge. No luck there, obviously.  :-)

Comment: "This *is* within an abstract-declarator" -> they mean not part of the abstract declarator of the last parameter of that same parameter type list. E.g `void (int...)` here, the `...` is not part of the abstract-declarator `int`, hence it is synonymous to `void(int, ...)`. If you would write `void(T...)` and `T` is a template parameter pack, `...` would be part of the abstract-declarator, and hence it would not be equivalent to `void(T, ...)`.

Comment: @Johannes: Ah, I think they could have been clearer about that. Does that sentence have any actual effect? It probably should be moved into the `[Note:]` block that follows.

Comment: Could you show some code that actually calls a function with this ...... notation, and what it means?

Comment: I am not a c++ standard doc lawyer, Can you please tell me what do you mean by "within an **abstract** -declarator"

Comment: @Mr.Anubis "abstract-declarator" is just a grammar production with little significance, except that it may include a `...`. It is "abstract" because it does not include any name to be declared, although in the context of a function declaration a non-abstract declarator (with a name) is also acceptable. If a name is supplied, though, it would go between the two ellipses.

Comment: "Furthermore, va_begin() in <cstdarg> requires a parameter before the varargs list, so the prototype f(...) specifically allowed by C++ is useless." -- It's only useless if you want to know what arguments were passed. `f(...)` is used heavily as a fallback function overload in template metaprogramming, where this information is not necessary (and where the function doesn't even actually get called).

Answer (score 4):

on vs2015 separating comma is essential in the template version:

```
    template <typename T, typename ... U>
    struct X<T(U...,...)> {};// this line is the important one
```

an example instantiation is:

```
    X<int(int...)> my_va_func;
```

regards,
FM.

Comment: I just noticed this too, it still happens. Bug report at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/437260/incorrect-c3546-compiler-error.html.

Comment: Good to know. Any references or citations to standads about this?

Comment: OK then. I'm no expert on the standard - I think that others have covered it in some detail above. If anyone cares to comment on the the Microsoft problem report then it might raise its priority. The report shows clang and gcc allowing what VC++ doesn't so I think we're probably on fairly strong ground.