# C++11 variadic function type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, c++11, std-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of “… …” token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625600/what-is-the-meaning-of-token)

There is a relatively new way to directly specify **function types** (at least, as template parameters). Don't know whether this is strictly C++11, but I've came across it while reading GCC 4.7's STL headers.

It's like this:

```
std::function<void(int, char**)> f;
```

And now, in header file `<functional>`, I see the following:

```
template <typename R, typename... A>
struct SomeStruct<R(A...)> { /* */ };
```

This is understandable: an explicit-specialization of `SomeStruct` for function types with return type `R` and arguments' types `A`.

But consider this declaration (on next line):

```
template <typename R, typename... A>
struct SomeStruct<R(A......)> { /* */ };
```

What does that double-ellipsis mean?

Comment: Ah, right. That's a duplicate, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally find it unclear, but if you know that these are equivalent, it makes more sense:

```
void example(int, char, ...); // C-style variadic arguments
void example(int, char...);   // equivalent: the comma before the ellipses is optional
```

So that specialization is just covering the case for when functions take the form:

```
R(A..., ...)
```

Such as in `sprintf`: `R` is `int`, `A...` is `char*` and `const char*`, and it's C-style variadic.