# Weird syntax - two ellipsis operators in parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of “… …” token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625600/what-is-the-meaning-of-token)

While looking through libc++'s header `<type_traits>`, I stumbled upon these class template specializations:

```
template<typename>
    struct is_function
    : public false_type { };

template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    : public true_type { };

template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>    // <-- Huh?
    : public true_type { };
```

There's three more pairs of specializations (`const`, `volatile` and `const volatile` variations), all in the same fashion.

It looks like two elipsis operators grouped together. The only mention of this I could find is on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/), where it says it can be also written with a space (`_ArgTypes... ...`) or a comma (`_ArgTypes..., ...`) but provides no explanation about what it means.

So, what does this syntax mean? What is the purpose of a specialization like this?