# A confusion about variadic templates in c++11 standard

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

What is the difference between the two functions?

```
template <class ...Types> void f(Types... args...){}
template <class ...Types> void g(Types... args){}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625600/what-is-the-meaning-of-token

Answer (score 7):

`f` is exactly the same as

```
template <class ...Types> void f(Types... args, ...){}
//                                            ^^^^^
```

I.e., it's just a plain old variadic parameter list from C. For historical reasons, it can be used without the usual `,` that is needed to seperate parameters. The difference to `g` is exactly that parameter.

Note that no arguments will ever be passed to the C-style variadic parameter list, since the C++-style variadic parameters will "swallow" *all* arguments.